# Javascript - list is not working

Tags: javascript

In the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3vbv61t6/#run

```js
function linkedlist() {
  this.head = null; //first line
}

linkedlist.prototype.add = function (val) {
  var node = {
    value: val,
    next: null
  };
  if (!this.head) {
    this.head = node; //Why is this done? wouldn't "main line"(below) make sure that this.head= null as in "first line"(above)
  } else {
    var current = this.head;
    while (current.next) {
      current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = node;
  }
  return node;
};

linkedlist.prototype.show = function () {
  var current = this.head;
  while (current) {
    console.log(current.value);
    current = current.next;
  }
};

linkedlist.prototype.insert = function (val, pos) {
  var current = this.head;
  var counter = 1;
  while (counter < pos - 1) {
    current = current.next;
    counter++;
  }

  var newnode = l.add(val)
  var temp = current.next; //temp - 5
  current.next = newnode; //
  newnode.next = temp;
};

var l = new linkedlist(); //main line
l.add(2);
l.add(7);
l.add(5);
l.add(8);
l.add(6);

l.show();

l.insert(4, 3);

//l.show(); //uncomment to see that there is a loop being generated.
```

```js
linkedlist.prototype.insert = function(val, pos) {
    var current = this.head;
    var counter = 1;
    while(counter < pos-1) {
        current = current.next;
        counter++;
    }

    var newnode = l.add(val)
    var temp = current.next; //temp - 5
    current.next = newnode; //
    newnode.next = temp;
};
```

the insert operation in the middle of a linked list is not working, seems like there is circular loop happening. Not sure where the loop is getting created

Also answer the comment in the fiddle

Comment: `var newnode = l.add(val)` <-- that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the new node twice, once correctly between 7 and 5, and then another time at the end (`l.add()`)

So your linked list looks somewhat like

```
2, 7, 4, 5, 8, 6, 4[, 5, 8, 6, 4[, 5, 8, 6, 4[, .... ] ] ]
      ^-----------^------------^------------^
       Same object, creating a circular loop
```

Inserting a loop at position n should be straightforward:

1. Find current node at n
2. Set newNode.next = Node[n].next (which becomes the node at n+1)
3. Set Node[n].next = newNode

Comment: True, inserting is simple. if you can point where am i adding it twice other than the pos

Comment: `var newnode = l.add(val)` there

Comment: @SecondRikudo You `add()` method already appends a new node to the end of the list. In `insert()` you afterwards try to inject it somewhere else, without deleting the old position.

Answer (score -2):

The Variable l is not set before.

Error must be here:

```
var newnode = l.add(val)
```